# Angular's template with external js libraries

Tags: templates, jquery-plugins, angularjs, digest, angularjs-directive

I have made element directive, which works with template through `templateUrl` parameter. This template contains fileupload input, which needs about 8 external js libraries (jquery fileupload plugin). If I have links to these js libraries in template (using standard script element), than everything works fine, but there is an error in browser console on loading:

```
Error: $digest already in progress
```

If I put the links to js libraries directly to the page, where I have my directive, there is no error, but it is not good way for reusability.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to trigger a `$digest` manually?

If this is the case, I strongly recommends you to change the approach, as you should let the Angular decides the best time for a `$digest`. If it's not possible to change, then you should be sure you're not calling a `$digest()/$apply()` inside an `$digest` cycle. One of the ways to do so is ensuring `!scope.$$phase`.

Comment: No, i don't use `$digest manually`. I have in directive only one `$http` method, no `$digest` neither any `$timeout`. So it seems that the problem is only in loading external libraries in template. 

Thanks for response.